# how to fetch iOS application documents in pc?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, data-sharing

is there any other way to share the iOS application document with PC without using iTunes or iExplorer?

I want to sync the iOS application with the PC and fetch all the documents in the document folder.In mac through iTunes it's possible;but in windows we can't access the folders and residing files.So there is any other way to access the document folder of iOS application from PC?

Comment: What about iTunes on Windows?

Comment: we can't access the folders/directories in the iOS application document folder by using iTunes in windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternate solution for this. This is Apple rule.Apple doesn't given the folder access. You have to install the iTunes in MAC or PC..